# questions wcf rest service with webclient

Tags: json, wcf, wcf-rest

I'm getting confused on a few things in regards to wcf rest.

1. If you call a login method, should I use a POST or GET? After implementing a POST, I started to find various articles saying you should only use post to update data, and get for retrieving data. Which is the most appropriate method?

If I had to change the Login method from a Post to a Get, how would I call this?

http://....myservice.svc/login/{username}/{passpord} or is there another way to call this?

Note that in my post method, I'm passing and returning data in json format.

2. I need to create a search function that requires to pass various parameters i.e. list, string, list, etc... I assume in this instance I would have to define GET method, but again how to I pass these list of objects? Convert them to json first and pass them as parameters?

A brief url sample would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I'll answer my own question based on further finding when researching it and remember that my answer is based on using JSON as parameters. I'm not sure how it would behave if xml was used as I did not try it.

1. It appears to make more sense to use POST when logging in as you do not want to display the information you are posting via a url. You could encrypt the data and pass it in the url using a GET method... Again I could be wrong, but that's how I interpreted the various articles I read.
2. Again, in this instance, it appears POST is the best solution if a) you require a large amount of data to be passed to your url and b) if you do not want to show this data to the user. If your query only requires simple parameters (i.e. userid, type, etc...) and you don't mind showing this info, you can use the GET method.

If you require to pass multiple parameters to a function, you should instead pass a single parameter. This parameter should be a single object. This object should be made of all the parameters you wanted to use in the first place, this way, when using the POST method, this object can easily be converted to JSON and it will handle passing multiple parameters through a single object and it will handle numeric, string, list<>, array<>, etc... very nicely.